# Python, compare strings in Counter and assign to closest match

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of input text written by humans. This text is imported to python and a Counter is generated. In the Counter, all the inputs from humans are listed and counted. At the end obtain something like:

"Input 1" : 3,

"Input 2" : 1,
...

The problem i have is that sometimes these inputs have spelling mistakes or are missing a space between words etc. How could I go through this list and compare it to some reference Inputs and asign to each counter row the total counts of the well written Inputs + the ones coming from the most similar Inputs with spelling mistakes. I know this falls on the NLP field but i can't really find a way to do this in a counter

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it would be helpful if you provided a clear input and expected output of your method

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt, without applying any ML, would be with [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
That will let you generate some concrete similarity between strings and make an educated guess about the connection between an 'error-free' string and one with a typo.

Comment: The problem I have is that the distance from mispelled text - > predicted  correct text in some of the cases is larger than mispelled text -> wrong prediction. Maybe I need to directly jump to ML?